# How to make a chain of ggplots and draw arrows between them?

Tags: r, ggplot2, drawing

For a project I need to draw some plots and put arrows between them as and indication of a sequence. I was wondering if I could do that with ggplot. Is it possible to draw a clean, big arrow with ggplot2 and add it two the final multiplot?

As an example I use this code to draw a plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar()
```

For the project I need to draw three plots like that. The result should be something like this:

[image]

Does anyone have a solution? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: How is it you are writing up your project? It may just be easier to do this within LaTeX?

Comment: I use rmarkdown to make an html page with the plots, and sometimes I generate pdf-documents, But I don't use LaTeX directly. I am not sure why it should be easier in LaTeX. For a long time now I have been wondering if it could be possible with ggplot2 to show changes in time between plots. It would be very helpful in my projects.

Comment: If you are using rmarkdown then you can add LaTeX code directly. You could use something such as `$\rightarrow$`. Then you just resize your plots as required. It's not the neatest or most direct solution, but I imagine it's a damn sight simpler than stitching 3 ggplots together.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(png)
download.file("https://www.wpclipart.com/signs_symbol/arrows/arrow_comic/Arrow_comic_right_gray.png",
              tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".png"),
              mode="wb")
arrow <- rasterGrob(readPNG(tf))
p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + 
  geom_bar() 
grid.arrange(p + guides(fill = "none"), 
             arrow, 
             p + guides(fill = "none"), 
             arrow, 
             p, 
             ncol=5, widths=c(2/10, 1.75/10, 2/10, 1.75/10, 2.5/10))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your solution! I think it will turn out to be a minor detail, but in my machine it says: `Error: could not find function "rasterGrob"`

Comment: oops, I forgot to load the grid package. Please try again.

Comment: it works and it's brilliant, exactly what I was looking for :-). Thanks again!

Comment: I know it's an addtional question but can you give me a hint about how to control the size of the arrow?

Comment: The `widths` parameter defines the width for each of the five elements. You can adjust the `1.75/10`s.